# Outlook 2013 add-in with VS 2010

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-pia, primary-interop-assembly

Sorry for asking such a stupid question, but i googled for about two hours and couldn't find an answer to my question:

How can i develop an Outlook 2013 add-in?

I have an add-in which was created in C# 2010 and for Outlook 2010. Now i would like to extend it in that way, that in Outlook 2013 are the two explorer events InlineResponse and InlineResponseClose.

I searched for a never version of the VSTO and PIA, but every website told me that these are for VS 2012 only?

Can someone of you explain me what i need to extend this add-in or show me a link where this is described? 
Sorry if this is a dumb question, but i'm a bit stressed out after that.

Comment: I haven't dug deeply enough yet to give anything like a complete answer, but Office 2013 has a _completely new add-in model_... they're going for something more like app store apps. I would expect a 2010 add-in to need a lot of re-working to support Office 2013.

Comment: The add-in model is completely changing in Office 2013, and is moving towards 'apps.'  I tried developing mobile WP8 app on VS2012 running on Win 7, that was a no go because WP8 SDK will only work on Win8 platform.

Comment: I know that they added a new way to extend Office what they are calling "apps" (html5+css+jscript+...). But this is a classic add-in and (for this version) they kept the add-in extensibility, so the add-in currently works without big problems.
My only problem is that i don't know how i can add a reference to the Outlook 2013 api to get these events... :-S

Comment: Install VS2012 express edition [then install VSTO ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905340.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is a classic Office add in dll and not one of the new 'apps' Microsoft introduced in this Office version. And you are right, as i want to keep it as a dll.

Now i solved my problem this way, that i use some unmanaged Code with interfaces and so on (Oleviewer helped a lot) to get the InlineResponse event.

Thanks for your answers here.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, you cannot.  Office 2013 is an 'app' based platform similar to the "Microsoft Marketplace' and will use JavaScript as the main communicative tool between different office applications. As a result, the basic project stack that now gets created with VS2012 for Office 2013 deployment is

- App1.html – Sample webpage
- App1.xml – Manifest file
- App1.js – Script file
- App1.css – Cascading Style Sheet
- Office.js – Office class library file

2010 will interpret this as a website.

Comment: This is only partially true. There is a new App concept for extending Office 2013, but "old style" addins still work.
Outlook 2013 supports COM add-ins just the same as Outlook 2012. It is supposed to be backward compatible.

Comment: @Bojan Hrnkas  as the question title suggests, the OP is trying to develop / upgrade a plugin to work in 2013 using Visual Studio 2010. You are correc to say it is made to be backwards compatible, I think the OP will need VS 2012 running on a Windows 8 platform to actually be able to upgrade the add-in.

Answer (score -2):

outlook 2010 add-in works with 2010 only. if you want to make this add-in compatible with all versions like 2007, 2010 and 2013. One way is to open that add-in VS2013 and compile it. You get few compilation error as this was developed with 2010. Fix those errors..thats it :). you will get what you want